# Почему результат выполнения BigDecimal.eval() имеет не полную точность, иногда теряет последнюю цифру числа?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

У меня есть список функций, одна из которых описана строкой `a * 12 + b`, в неё, в одном из случаев, передаются значения `a = 1369005, b = 101845`. Исходя из этого уже понятно, что результат выполнения должен заканчиваться на 5. В результате выполнения указанной ниже строчки кода, я получаю ответ `1.652990E+7`.

```java
BigDecimal eval = expression.get().eval();
```

Что в итоге преобразуется в:

```
long value : 16529900 
double value : 1.65299E7
```

Я находил подобную проблему и было указано, что данный метод так же выполняет метод stripTrailingZeros() у самого BigDecimal, потому я переписал обработку результата на такую форму:

```java
BigDecimal eval = expression.get().eval(false);
```

Это не помогло.

Doc.: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/bigdecimal_striptrailingzeros.htm

Comment: Что такое (т. е. какого типа) ваше `expression` и что возвращает его метод `get()` и что за метод `eval()`? А еще лучше поместите такой кусок кода, чтобы его можно было у себя выполнить, чтобы воспроизвести проблему (оставив в нем только то, что относится к делу, конечно). Это вопрос скорее не по `BigDecimal`, а по этому классу, который вы используете.

Answer (score 0):

Не понятны ваши проблемы но

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {

    BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(1369005);
    BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(101845);
    BigDecimal c = a.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(12)).add(b);

    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(c.doubleValue());
}
```

выводит `16529905` и `1.6529905E7` как и ожидалось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]